# Noun + to infinitive

Tags: grammaticality

I was told by someone, several years ago, that *It is **the tool to fasten** the bolts* is not correct.

I often find the following sentences that are considered correct.

> I will send **a technician to fix** your car.

> He has **a permit to stay** here for a week.

Those three sentences contain a *noun + infinitive* phrase. Why should the first sentence be considered incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are all grammatical and idiomatic:

It is the tool for fastening the bolts.

It is the tool used to fasten the bolts.

It's the tool to fasten the bolts with. <sup>informal/colloquial</sup>

It's the tool to fasten the bolts. <sup>informal/colloquial</sup>

The scalpel is a knife to cut a patient open. <sup>informal/colloquial</sup>

Answer (score 1):

**It is the tool to fasten the bolts** can be acceptable in English, but only under the circumstances where you have a unique tool that is used to fasten a specific set of bolts. This sentence is not acceptable if you mean that this is a tool to fasten all types of bolts. Where you are talking about non-specific types of bolts you do not use the definite article before the word 'bolts'.

Without changing your sentence majorly, sentence A could best be said as:

> It is a tool to fasten bolts.

While that sentence is grammatically correct, a native English speaker would more likely say:

> It is a tool for fastening bolts.